# Create Template for Page with List and CEWP

Tags: 2010, list-view, content-editor-web-part

In our portal we have a List that acts as a signup sheet, and above it we have inserted a CEWP to provide some directions.

Is there a way that I can save the combination as a template of some kind?  Right now we have to add the CEWP manually every time, and that is just too much for a few of the secretaries.

So, here is what we do now:

1. Create a new custom list (based on a saved custom list template)
2. Add a Content Editor Web Part to that list-view page
3. Find an older list and copy the text from the old CEWP
4. Enter Edit Mode in the new CEWP and past the copied text (this assures the text formatting and basic message will be standardized)
5. Set custom permissions for the list

It's a list with a place at the very top to have directions (I have been using a CEWP); users need to be able to read the list and the directions at the same time.  I am not concerned with New/Edit/Display forms.

It's way too many steps. What I need is one step.  The secretary should be able to create a custom page that contains all these things already.  The custom permissions can be done via workflow, but there is no way I know of to have something she can add that contains both the list and the CEWP.

Comment: Is it same list on different sites/subsites, Do you want a blank CEWP in list above LVWP. Or New form?

Comment: Can you please explain some more information regarding your question ?